# Closed form to series

Tags: summation

Is there a closed form of the series

$$
\sum_{d=0}^D F^d
$$

where D is a finite integer, not $\infty$, like in [power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series)?

Comment: It is a high-school formula: $\;\dfrac{1-F^{D+1}}{1-F}$.

Comment: Is $F$ a number or something else?

Comment: @Mnifldz: Yes, it is an integer.

Comment: @Bernard: It is? Sorry, I couldn't find it and it is not obvious to me to be honest. Does it have a name, so I can search for the proof?

Comment: It is  directy derived from the factorisation  formula $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}) with $a=1$. I don't whether it has a worldwide name. I learnt it at the end of middle-school, and it is user later for the sum of a geometric series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method for demonstrating the formula given by Bernard in the comments above is called *telescoping*.  The trick is to observe that the sum can be written as:

$$
S \;\; =\;\; \sum_{d=0}^D F^d \;\; =\;\; 1 + F + F^2 + \ldots + F^D.
$$

If I multiply $S$ by an additional copy of $F$ we obtain:

$$
FS \;\; =\;\; F\left (1 + F + F^2 + \ldots + F^D \right ) \;\; =\;\; F + F^2 + \ldots + F^D + F^{D+1}.
$$

We can now subtract one equation from the other to obtain the telescoping effect:
\begin{eqnarray*}
S - FS & = & \left (1 + F + F^2 + \ldots + F^D \right ) - \left( F + F^2 + \ldots + F^D + F^{D+1} \right ) \\
& = & 1 - F^{D+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Notice that the above subtraction eliminates all but the first and last terms.  Acknowledging that $S$ was the sum we obtained, we can isolate it by noticing that $S - FS = S(1-F)$.  Dividing both sides we find:

$$
S \;\; =\;\; \sum_{d=0}^D F^d \;\; =\;\; \frac{1 - F^{D+1}}{1-F}.
$$